# How to use my dual monitors separately?

Tags: multiple-monitors, 17.04

So i've been trying a lot to configure this out.I'm pretty with  linux and can't really make it work.My monitors work fine on mirror mode but can't make them to work separately .I'm using nvidia graphics card(gtx 1060).I would appreciate some help! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Go to `System Settings` > `Displays` and uncheck `Mirror Displays`. Drag the displays according the disposition you want and click on `Apply`.

If working fine, click on `Keep this configuration`.

Comment: I think OP means completely separately... not a big screen in two monitor.

Comment: I have tried that.I don't want them to work as a big screen,just want them to work totally seperately or have different workspaces on each monitor.And it didn't work anyways,idk why.I don't want the screen to stretch.Thanks for answering btw.

Comment: I'm not sure it that helps, but Unity places all its elements (launcher, global menu and notification area) in all displays.